# Group Action: Group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

In my group theory notes I have the following:

> The Group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows: $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$: $m.x \to (-1)^mr$

in this notation $m.x$ defines the group action.

I am unsure how to obtain the RHS: $(-1)^mr$...

Comment: What do you mean, "obtain the RHS"? They are *defining* the action that way.

Comment: Presumably it should be $m \cdot r := (-1)^m r$.

Comment: If $m\cdot x$ disturbs you, says that the action is $A:\mathbb Z\times \mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb Z$ defined by $A(m,r)=(-1)^m r$. But notice that an action define an "external law" on a set. That's why we use $m\cdot x$.

Comment: The right-hand side $(-1)^mr$ _defines_ the group action, using regular, good-old exponentiation and multiplication. The left-hand side $m.r$ is just to establish a choice of notation.

Comment: Wait, what is the question?

Comment: Perhaps I fundamentally misunderstood the idea of Group Action: It seems that the Group Action must have a defined operation, which in this case is defined by $m.x \to (-1)^mr$. So obtaining the RHS is pointless as it is the definition assigned the the LHS. 

Is this interpretation of you comments correct? Could I equally have defined a group action of $m.x \to (-1)^mr^2$?

Comment: @Hawk My initial question was how I get the relation $m.x \to (-1)^mr$

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane, I thought that's a definition of your action. If you want to *check* that it is an action, that's a different question.

Comment: @Hawk with respect to my earlier statement: Could I have equally chosen any arbitrary group action in this case?

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane, can you give an example of your arbitrary action? It needs to satisfy the group action axioms.

Comment: Ok brilliant. That's all I needed to know! Thank you everyone for some great help you have saved several of us hours of pain on this issue!

Comment: You have an $x$ and an $r$ in your question that are probably supposed to be the same thing. Your question would also be clearer if you used the more standard notations $(m, x) \mapsto (-1)^mx$ rather than $m, x \to (-1)^mx$.

Comment: @RobArthan Alas... I would have loved notes that used $(m,x)$ vs. $m.x$, it is incredibly difficult to differentiate $m.x$ and $m\cdot x$ in size 10 font! In fact I will start using this notation from now as it's clearer...

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify the issue a bit more, since it wasn't very explicit in the comments.

The quote says:

> The group ... acts on ... as follows.

This is misleading (or written by a non-native English speaker) since it suggests that there is one known action which is now going to be described. Hence it wasn't surprising that you were asking how the action was derived.

The quote should have said:
$\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$

> The group $(\zz,+)$ acts on $\rr$ via $\bullet$ where $m \bullet r = (-1)^m r$ for any $m \in \zz$ and $r \in \rr$.

This conveys that $\bullet$ is just one action. There are other possible ways that $(\zz,+)$ can act on $\rr$, such as:

> The group $(\zz,+)$ acts on $\rr$ via $\diamond$ where $m \diamond r = m r$ for any $m \in \zz$ and $r \in \rr$.

Now in both cases we would have a statement that is either true or false. If we wish to prove it, then we could expand the definition of actions and verify the conditions one by one. Alternatively we could prove some general theorem about actions. For example the following is always true:

> The group $(\zz,+)$ acts on any ring $R$ via $\cdot$ where $0 \cdot r = 0_R$ and $(z+1) \cdot r = z \cdot r + r$ for any $z \in \zz$ and $r \in R$. (Here $\cdot$ is inductively defined.)